# Ruby Console: How to Keep 'gets' from adding a new line when the user inputs

Tags: ruby

Why does `gets` always add a new line when the user inputs the number of boxes?

I want the next print statement to be shown on the same line as the input.

```
    print "Enter the number of boxes: "
    boxes = gets.chomp
    print "Enter number of columns to print the boxes in: "
    columns = gets.chomp
```

I want output to look like this:

```
Enter the number of boxes: 47 Enter number of columns to print the boxes in: 4
```

I don't want to begin a new line until after the second input is received.

Comment: Nathan, the problem is not something which can easily be mitigated. But think about it, after the user types in 47, what do they press?

Comment: Are you saying that using the **return key** itself is what passes the newline character?  could a method be created to tack onto gets (gets.nonewline) to remove the newline?

Comment: I am not sure if it is really worth the effort?

Comment: okay I lumped everything into one print statement seperated by commas.  The output is correct but when the script is run nothing prints, it waits for both inputs first and then runs the print statement. output is 
~./boxes
20
2
Enter number of boxes to print: 20Enter number of colums: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows you can do it like this, otherwise you would need a similar read_char method that works in your OS

```
def read_char #only on windows
  require "Win32API"
  Win32API.new("crtdll", "_getch", [], "L").Call
end

def get_number
  number, inp = "", 0
  while inp != 13
    inp = read_char
    if "0123456789"[inp.chr]
      number += inp.chr
      print inp.chr  
    end
  end
  number
end

print "Enter the number of boxes: "
boxes = get_number
print " Enter number of columns to print the boxes in: "
columns = get_number
puts ""

puts "boxes: #{boxes}"
puts "columns: #{columns}"

# gives
# Enter the number of boxes: 5 Enter number of columns to print the boxes in: 6
# boxes: 5
# columns: 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use IO/console and build up your input a character at a time:

```
require 'io/console'

def cgets(stream=$stdin)
  $stdin.echo = false
  s = ""
  while true do
    c = stream.getc
    return s if c == "\n"
    s << c
  end
end
```

The issue is echoing the input back; getting the character out when it *isn't* a newline is a bit problematic (at least locally, not on my regular machine). Also, since you're getting the characters manually, it removes normal readline functionality, so behavior will be system-dependent e.g., Unixy systems might lose their backspace etc.

That said, yuck; IMO on the console this is an unexpected UI pattern, and keeping the input on two lines is more obvious, and more common.